# TFS -Jenkins multi branch project

Tags: jenkins, tfs

Hi I am using Jenkins for CI/CD setup. I want to make the Jenkins project/job customization so that during runtime i can select which branch it has get the code and build from. Please let me know how to achieve this as TFS holds the workspace(TFS) pointing to one branch at a time on a particular jenkins job workspace.
I am using pipeline project btw.
Do i have to have separate jobs for separate branch or it can be done in single job only.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parameter like in job configuration:

[image]

And later configure the git repo to build `$branch`:

[image]

When you with a build with params you can set the tag you want to build.

Comment: Actually Branch specifier option does not come in TFS plugin. I am checking out TFS repo and not Git.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pipeline, u can wrap the git plugin with a dir block, it clones the repositories in runtime to the specific folder:

```
#!groovy
node ('slave9') {
  stage {
    // clone master branch of repo1 into folder f1
    dir('f1') {
      git([url: "git@gitlab.xxx.local:PRJ/proj1.git", branch: "master"])
    }
    // clone BR2 branch from repo2 into folder f2
    // BR2 is a string parameters passed in from jenkins job ui
    dir('f2') {
      git([url: "git@gitlab.xxx.local:PRJ/proj2.git", branch: "${BR2}"])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am checking out TFS repo. i think the above script is for git